# How can I position an arrow and some text between two plots in a GraphicsRow expression?

Tags: graphics

I want to combine three graphics using the code

```
p1 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 8}];
p2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 8}];
p3 = Graphics[{{Arrowheads[Medium], 
     Arrow[{{0.1, 0}, {0.4, 0}}]}, {Inset[  
      Style["a\[RightArrow]b", FontSize -> Scaled[0.1], Italic, 
       FontFamily -> "Times"], { 0.1, 0.1  }]}
    }];

GraphicsRow[{p1, p3, p2}]
```

The result I get is
[image]

I played with the size and positions in $p3$, but I did not succeed to get a nice result like this
[image]

Any comments or hints are appreciated.

Comment: Just adjust the positioning inside `Inset` to e.g. `{0.25, 0.03}` instead of the `{0.1, 0.1}` you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correcting your inset placement as MarcoB suggests will work, but why bother with `Inset`? Why not do it directly with `Text`? Like so:

```
p1 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 8}];
p2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 8}];
p3 =
  Graphics[
    {Arrowheads[Medium], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {.3, 0}}],
     Text[Style["a\[RightArrow]b", 14, Italic], {.15, .05}]},
    PlotRangePadding -> {{.1, .1}, Automatic},
    ImageSize ->] 200];
GraphicsRow[{p1, p3, p2}]
```

[image]